# Qt Library not found when I try to run an Application I build on another Mac

Tags: qt, dll

I built an Application using Qt. It runs fine on my Mac. But when I try to copy and run it on another Mac, it is complaining:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
```

How should I build the Application such that it is fully portable?

Comment: Read https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/osx-deployment.html#macdeploy

Comment: nowadays you’ll also have to look into codesigning and notarization I’m afraid.